# How to enable the experimental or cutting-edge edition of Opera Dragonfly?

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

I saw on the [Dragonfly features page](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/features/) that there are experimental and cutting-edge editions of Dragonfly in addition to the stable edition.

When I open Dragonfly within Opera, it looks like the stable version is being used. How do I have Opera use the experimental or cutting-edge editions of Dragonfly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First open opera:config#DeveloperTools|DeveloperToolsURL . Then enter the URL for the edition that you want to use:

- stable (the default):

  https://dragonfly.opera.com/app/stable/
- cutting-edge:

  https://dragonfly.opera.com/app/cutting-edge/
- experimental:

  https://dragonfly.opera.com/app/experimental/

Comment: .. as written on a sidebar of [dragonfly blog](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/)